# One question about nega-cyclic Hadamard matrices

Tags: co.combinatorics, matrices, combinatorial-designs, orthogonal-matrices

Let $n$ be a multiple of $4$, is there any $n \times n$ negacyclic Hadamard matrix? If yes - how to construct it? If no - why?

Here an $n \times n$ nega-cyclic matrix is a square matrix of the form:

\begin{align}
 \begin{bmatrix} 
x_1 & x_2 & \cdots & x_{n-1} & x_n \\ 
-x_n & x_1 & \cdots & x_{n-2} & x_{n-1} \\ 
\vdots & \vdots& \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 
-x_3 & -x_4 & \cdots &  x_1 & x_2 \\ 
-x_2 & -x_3 & \cdots & -x_n & x_1 \\ \end{bmatrix}. 
\end{align}

An $n \times n$ Hadamard matrix is a matrix whose entries are either $1$ or $-1$ and whose rows are mutually orthogonal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Such matrices do not exist as from the parity consideration already first two rows cannot be orthogonal.